# Troubles with addFeature in Openlayers by using SelectFeature control

Tags: openlayers-2

I'm having troubles with a highlight layer which I created on a map dynamically to put the selected feature on the top of all layers, so I can see it despite of a polygon layer which has been set visible on the SelectFeature method. It is working well so long I don't try to unselect it. 
The functions are like:

```
 var HighlightLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('HighlightLayer', {
        visibility: false
        }
    );

function selectedFeaturesSchulenEinzug(event) {
        HighlightLayer.addFeatures([event.feature]);

        // a try with addFeatures but without event.object works well
        //HighlightLayer.addFeatures([OrigVectorLayer.features[0]]);

        HighlightLayer.setVisibility(true);

        //switch on the polygon layer
        PolygLayer.setVisibility(true);
}

  function unselectFeatureEinzug() {

        // switch off the polygon layer
       PolygLayer.setVisibility(false);

       // remove the features and switch off the highlight layer
      HighlightLayer.removeAllFeatures();
      HighlightLayer.setVisibility(false);
  }
```

It looks like the event.feature object makes the trouble when I click out the layer. Maybe it tries to put a new event.feature into the HighlightLayer and simultaneously removeAllFeatures. However, when I clear the unselect function and it contains nothing, I have the same problem: it tries to do something and after a while the message prompts that the script doesn't answer.
When I try to make the same with a not dynamic feature (like in the script above in the comment), I don't have any troubles and the unselect method can be executed.

Does anybody has experience with a trouble like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the source of the trouble and it is quite specific to my map application, but maybe others face the problem sometimes, too.

So: addFeature function with an event handler takes the event.feature "out" of the original layer. As I switched off my original layer with setVisibility(false), the layer missed a feature by switching on again resp. there were contradictory declinations for the styling of the feature.

So I build the HighlightLayer new by taking the geometry and attributions of the event.feature. Now everything is fine...